# Javascript loop issue when combined with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am trying to make it so that every time I click it changes colors. However I am having issues getting the loop to work. It works once, but then doesn't work afterwards, I have tried a few different methods but haven't been able to make it work more than once. Any help would be great!

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

</script>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="490" style= background:black;>
</canvas>
<script>

</script>
<script>
function colorChecker(colorChanger) {
    if (colorChanger == 1) {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'green';}
    if (colorChanger == 2) {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';}
    if (colorChanger == 3) {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';}
    if (colorChanger == 4) {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'purple';}
    if (colorChanger == 5) {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';}
    }



var onOff = true;
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
c.addEventListener('click',function() {
    var colorChanger = 1;
     if (colorChanger < 6) {
        colorChanger++;
        colorChecker(colorChanger);
    }
    else {
        colorChanger = 1;
        colorChecker(colorChanger);
    }
}
);
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = 'green';




var fallingWords = ["Java", "if", "else", "elsif", "True", "False", "null", "C++", "Python", "Math.random()", "X", "Y", "while", "do", "for", "loop", "import", "var", "let", "()", "{}", "arrays", "and", "or", "not"];


var things = [];
var objectNumber = 150;
for (var i = 0; i < objectNumber; i++) {
    var a = {};
    //randomly pick one tag
    a.code = fallingWords[Math.round(Math.random() * fallingWords.length)];
    a.x = Math.random() * 800;
    a.y = Math.random() * 490 - 490;
    a.speed = Math.random() * 10;
    things.push(a);
}

setInterval(function () {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 490);
    for (var i = 0; i < objectNumber; i++) {
        var a = things[i];
        ctx.fillText(a.code, a.x, a.y);
        a.y += a.speed;
        if (a.y > 600) a.y = -50;
    }
}, 90);

if (onOff === false) {
    objectNumber = 0;    
}
else {
    objectNumber = 150;   
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Move `var colorChanger = 1;` outside the click function.

Comment: Please provide the least amount of code that demonstrates your issue. Also, from a coding point of view, your `colorChecker` function should use a `switch/case` block.

Comment: I don't see how jQuery applies to this.

Comment: As @j08691 points out, there is no jQuery in here...

Answer (score 0):

In your event listener, `colorChanger` is **always** 1:

```
.addEventListener('click',function() {

    //THIS NEEDS TO BE DECLARED OUTSIDE THIS FUNCTION
    var colorChanger = 1;
     if (colorChanger < 6) {
        colorChanger++;
        colorChecker(colorChanger);
    }
    else {
        colorChanger = 1;
        colorChecker(colorChanger);
    }
}
);
```